# "* alias was not found. Maybe you forgot to join it?" with skip and take and joins

Tags: node.js, postgresql, left-join, typeorm

I use query builder and have few joins in my request (by using `leftJoinAndMapMany`). Because of joins I need to use `skip` and `take` for pagination, because with `offset` and `limit` it works not as I need.
So, if I use `offset` and `limit` the request working ok and I don't have any exceptions. But if I use `skip` and `take` I have `""User"" alias was not found. Maybe you forgot to join it?` (don't know why there are two quotes, maybe this is a problem?)
The sql query debug shows normal query which I can run in db and it works. So problem is on typeorm side... If I remove joins it works ok with `skip` and `take`.

```
const dbQuery: SelectQueryBuilder<T> = userRepository.createQueryBuilder('User');
dbQuery.leftJoinAndMapMany(...);
dbQuery.skip(skip);
dbQuery.take(take);
```

UPD:
I've checked `typeorm` lib and found `QueryExpressionMap.prototype.findAliasByName = function (aliasName)` function and found that aliasName comes here with quotes, so I added there peace of code to remove these quotes and it works now, but not sure if it is a good solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was `orderBy`, in case of `skip` and `take` you should provide `User.id` but not `"User"."id"`(like in case when you use `limit/offset`)